# What is the correct way to use the "scroll-event" signal (on an indicator) for Qt?

Tags: application-development, indicator, qt, scrolling

I am again at the same position, when I had the question [What is the correct way to use g_signal_connect() in C++ for dynamic unity quicklists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180395/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-g-signal-connect-in-c-for-dynamic-unity-quick)

There I was informed that the signature for my static method was incorrect and that I had to add a guint argument in front of the others. Now I have the same problem but for the function called for the "scroll-event" signal that I want to make on to my indicator.

More specifically:

```
//connecting indicator with the scroll-event and altogether with the function indicator_scrolled
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(appindicator), "scroll-event", G_CALLBACK(&indicator_scrolled), (gpointer)this);
```

This is the function indicator_scrolled:

```
gboolean indicator_scrolled(GtkStatusIcon  *status_icon, GdkEventScroll *event, gpointer data){
    cout << "The indicator was scrolled\n";
    MainWindow* m = (MainWindow*)data;
    m->action_on_scroll();
}
```

I can see the "Indicator was scrolled" message but then the program crashed. Adding a guint argument in front of the others didn't solved the problem.

So, what is the correct signature for this function so as to make it work? How can I find what is the correct signature each time so as to avoid this kind of questions? (At the other question user George Edison talked about `valgrind` but he did not clarify)

Please do not advice that AppIndicators are not the correct way to go with Ubuntu+Qt, please see question [Make sniqt recognize all tray abilities (or create a working indicator in Qt)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224291/make-sniqt-recognize-all-tray-abilities-or-create-a-working-indicator-in-qt)

Edit: After tests I coincidentally found that a guint argument needs to be placed between the GtkStatusIcon and GdkEventScroll arguments. But I would really want to know a way to find out what is the correct function signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the reference manual: https://web.archive.org/web/20130604060558/http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/c/appindicator/libappindicator-app-indicator.html#AppIndicator-scroll-event

```
arg0 : The AppIndicator object
arg1 : How many steps the scroll wheel has taken
arg2 : (type Gdk.ScrollDirection) Which direction the wheel went in
user_data : user data set when the signal handler was connected.
```

Comment: I had a look at the source code of another application implementing what I wanted to and its arguments were completely different than the ones specified in the link you provided me with. Thanks for this, it works flawlessly :)

Answer (score 1):

As of today, after some search-and-try, this is my working scroll-event callback:

```
static void indicator_scrolled(AppIndicator *indicator, guint steps, GdkScrollDirection direction)
{
    if (direction == GDK_SCROLL_DOWN)
        g_print("DOWN\n");
    else if (direction == GDK_SCROLL_UP)
        g_print("UP\n");
    else if (direction == GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH)
       g_print("SMOOTH\n");
}
```

During a scroll I am receiving just one UP/DOWN, and then some SMOOTH (in the same direction).

I have no idea on how to manage the smooth direction, as I should need the GdkEventScroll structure not seen anywhere; 
I am implementing a volume up/down on my app indicator and I will maintain a global direction flag so the following smooth will be applied on the current direction, but I think this is just a workaround on a messy and poor documented implementation which is libappindicator.

Comment: Congrats on finding a working callback function for you. Welcome to the site !